# Cannot find my Word Documents.

Tags: microsoft-word-2011

I've had Word as my document program since purchasing my machine 4 years ago. After being hacked, Geek squad had to wipe my machine clean and I can no longer find my Word Documents.

I have hundreds of Music files (guitar tabs) that I can no longer access. This has only cropped up since upgrading to Windows 10. How do I locate these files, and pin them to the start bar so they are readily available?

Comment: Did they format or simply install another version of Windows?

Comment: If they wiped your machine those files are lost.  You can try file recovery software of your choice to attempt to recovery your file, but I can guarantee, you won't recover all of them

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to be clearer.  You said that the Geek squad wiped your machine, which means the documents were wiped, and then said it happened after an upgrade.

Comment: As always, the advice is to restore from your back-up. If you have 4 years of documents without a back-up, then you are learning a very hard lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you hired a third party to do some work on your computer and now you have a problem, you should be able to call them and ask them if they know where those files are or if they took a backup. If they didn't back up your files, personally I would not employ their services ever again.

Second, before reading anything below, the best solution to this problem would be to restore from the backup you made before the problem. If you don't have one, then you've learned a valuable lesson.

---

On to the question at hand: the answer is **it depends**.

It depends on how they went about "wiping" or "upgrading" your computer. If they simply reinstalled Windows without doing a multi-pass disk wipe, it's *possible* the files could be restored using a recovery software such as [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva). "Possible" here is used loosely. There are absolutely no guarantees that any of your files are recoverable in this situation, and the chances are extremely slim you'll be able to recover all of them

If they did a drive wipe using a formatting tool, the files are gone. You would have to spend thousands (or possible tens of thousands) for a forensics team to recover files after a format such as that. Even then, it would likely be *fragments* of files, not complete ones.

If they upgraded your operating system, your files should still be there if they did an in-place upgrade (upgrade the OS without wiping the drive). If you can't find them, we can't help with that, but Geeksquad probably could if they made proper backups or documented what they did.